# MMORPG moving protocol mechanism

Tags: networking, system, game-engine

I would like to build from scratch a kind of small (extremely small and simple) MMORPG game with click movements inside a given grid (something like an online Pokemon game). When I click on a cell, the player will move to reach the pointed area (using a pathfinding algorithm such as A*). But, I have no idea about how to build the network protocol of the movement system. And, googling the subject doesn't seem to help me a lot. I need to make a choice: - either I send a message to the server each time I move from one cell to another (which isn't efficient at all because if we are in a 100ms latency network, I can only sens 10movements/sec and if I ask the server to acknowledge the movement it can only do 5moves/sec) - either I send a message each time the player wants to change its direction (it clicks on another cell). The client sends periodically its position to the server and it checks if it's coherent with the destination.

The second solution looks a lot better than the first one and I think that a real game systems must implement that strategy. Am I wrong?

Also, how can we build systems based on that solution that doesn't let a modified (hacked) client be able to send fake positions and teleport anywhere they want? Does real systems implement somethink like a "incoherent sent position" system that will try to try to detect and fix those problems?

Or, is there something simpler to implement? Thank you very much

Comment: Is the game going to be turn based? if so I would collect all movements before the turn is over then I would send them as a package to the servers. and go from there. Now if it is real time then yes you want to send every movement to the server.

Comment: Good question :) No, it's real time but I do not need to send each movement to the server, I just need a kind of synchronisation between the client and the server (the local and the online positions must always be quite close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ScarletMerlin's answers I think there's a simple solution to my problem.

When the player wants to move from one position (for instance 0,0) to another (for instance 10,10), it sends a "MOVE 10 10" message to the server.

Then, only the server will apply the pathfinding algorithm and send after each move the position to the client. (for instance, by message CURRENTLY_ON X Y). Then, the client will update the position of the player.

It's a kind of automatic synchronisation from the server to the client. It also solves the problem of the first solution (one move and one ACK per movement) thanks to pipeling. For instance, if the network has a 1000ms delay and a move is set 50ms, we will just receive messages at time 1000, 1050, 1100, 1150, ... So, we will just feel the lag when the player is changing its direction. 
The user will also feel some lag when changing from one direction to another but if we assume that the delay is quite low and symetric (it doesn't seems to be a too strong assumption), it won't be so much percepted (as the change direction will often arrive before the sending of the CURRENTLY_ON message and the server can interrupt its current action (going straight on) to handle the new one).

Answer (score 1):

In a realtime game I would create a panthing mechanic. I would use a formula such as: Speed * time = distance.

now if you run the same logic in the client and the server you only need to send the movement logic at the beginning and the sever can answer with a finish message when the distance is traveled. (compare at the end to prevent cheating. the server always wins)

Now if the client cancels in the movement to go somewhere else, you send a cancelation of panthing and the time that you traveled. The same goes when changing the panthing (in this case you send a new path staring at a new time and place).

Comment: Ok so, you would use something like the second approach. How would you cope with security problems? For instance, you are cancelling a movement. I think you must send the X,Y postion on which you were before cancelling (because if not some synchronisation problems would lead to inconsistency between client and server). And how would you prevent sending fake X,Y positions (like if a hacker tries to send its own messages to teleport the player)? 
Thank you :)

Comment: The server is running the path logic too (server knows where you are at any given time).  so if you want to move to x,y from 0,0. the server starts counting the time since you told him you were moving. if you cancel, you tell the server I stop moving at x time so I must be at y position (hence all you need is the time the path was cancel.)

Comment: Yes but I think that the synchronisation between a client and a server is a much more complex problem (what time can we use? client time? server time? how can we share it at some milliseconds). For instance if the latency can vary from 0 ms to 1000ms, using that system can have very unpredictible results. Am I wrong?

Comment: Latency is always an issue not matter the game. If you want real time you are restricted to how fast the client can talk to the sever. In League of Legends if you have lag you are stuck and can't  move until the sever gives the ok. Your server is the master so the time you want to use is the time your request arrived at the server.

Comment: I think I have a better sight of the solution. 
If I am on 0,0 and I say move to 5,0 I send "MOVE 5 0"
And then, the server will reply 
"OK 1 0" then "OK 2 0" then "OK 3 0" and the client will only display the character at the good postion when it receives the OK message from the server? 
(my previous vision was to move without waiting acknowledgement from the server which is not so a good idea). 

With that solution, the latency will only impact when the player changes its direction and not when it moves straight on thanks to the "pipelining" of the OK messages. Good idea :)